# References on parameter identification for ODE models from time-series data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, nonlinear-optimization, parameter-estimation, inverse-problems

Setting: Say I've got a system of ODEs, e.g. a generalized Lotka-Volterra system of the form:

$$\dot x_i = x_i \left( r_i + \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} x_j \right), 
\quad 1 \leq i,j \leq n,$$

and I count with time-series data of all $x_i$ at a finite number of time points.

Goal: Estimate the parameters $r_i$ and $b_{ij}$.

What are some good references (papers, textbooks, whatever) on this particular kind of inverse problems? I guess what I mean by "this kind of inverse problems" is mostly inverse problems with the following characteristics:

1. The relevant model is a system of ODEs.
2. The ODEs are nonlinear.
3. The data to be modelled is in time-series form.

Most of the textbooks on inverse problems I've skimmed so far, e.g. [Astler](https://www.elsevier.com/books/parameter-estimation-and-inverse-problems/aster/978-0-12-804651-7) or [Tarantola](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898717921?mobileUi=0), don't seem particularly illuminating on this kind of inverse problems.

Comment: Perhaps this reference can help https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/35/5/830/5078478